# Click method is not working on a Salesforce webpage after the new update of Chromedriver. How to handle this with the same method?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, click, selenium-chromedriver, salesforce-lightning

Note: This has been observed on **Salesforce** website in **Lightning** mode only.
After update of Chromedriver to version 77.0.3865.40 , the generic click() method is not working to click on a web element. I have to use the Actions class to get the job done (But it is not recommended in our framework). Can anyone help with why the standard click method is not working ?

Answer (score 0):

I'm facing the same behavior right now but with isDisplayed method, for some reason when RemoteWebDriver makes a request to WebElement, the value of the httpResponse is null. That is causing NullPointerException when isDisplayed method is trying to cast the value to Boolean.

As a workaround we're currently using a ChromeDriver 76.0.3809.126.

Looks like a chromedriver v. 77.0.3865.40 bug to me.

Comment: I created a function where I clicked on Elements via JavaScript. That made it work.